# Regular Expression to match the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for Regular Expression search pattern to find data within `$<` and `>$`.

```
string pattern = "\b\$<[^>]*>\$";
```

is not working.

Thanks,

Comment: What language is this in? maybe `(?s)\$<(.+?)>\$`. Data will be in `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: "\$<([^>]*)>\$" should work fine, and give you the contents in group $1. No idea what the \b is doing there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
\$<(?:(?!\$<|>\$)[\s\S])*>\$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV5cF3/1)

This way, you will match only the closest boundaries.

Your regex does not match because you do not allow `>` in-between your markers, and you are using `\b` where you most probably do not have a word boundary.

If you do not want to get the delimiters in the output, use capturing group:

```
\$<((?:(?!\$<|>\$)[\s\S])*)>\$
   ^                      ^
```

And the result [will be in Group 1](https://regex101.com/r/zV5cF3/2).

In C#, you should consider declaring all regex patterns (whenever possible) with the help of a verbatim string literal notation (with `@""`) because you won't have to worry about doubling backslashes:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\$<(?:(?!\$<|>\$)[\s\S])*>\$");
```

Or, since there is a singleline flag (and this is preferable):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\$<((?:(?!\$<|>\$).)*)>\$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
var res = rx.Match(text).Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked :). I voted. code is                                                                            string text = "$< abc.fgc() >$ normal $< abc() >$ 234 ${ abc = }$";
string patter = @"\$<((?:(?!\$<|>\$)[\s\S])*)>\$";
          
Match m = Regex.Match(text, patter, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
{
     Trace.WriteLine(g.Value);
 }                                                                                                                                    But it is only matching the $< abc.fgc() >$ and abc.fgc().... But I need only abc.fgc()  and abc().

Comment: I do not understand: does it work for you? The regex [does not match `abc.fgc()`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24%3c((%3f%3a(%3f!%5c%24%3c%7c%3e%5c%24)%5b%5cs%5cS%5d)*)%3e%5c%24&i=%24%3c+abc.fgc()+%3e%24+and+abc.fgc()) alone, only when it is inside `$<....>$`. The value you need is in Group 1. Please let me know if you still need more help with this. In order to get `abc()`, you will need another pattern, like [`Regex.Replace("abc.fgc()", @"\.[^()]+", string.Empty);`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5b%5e()%5d%2b&i=abc.fgc()&r=&o=s) on the result of the previous extraction.

Comment: Yes. I need help in C#. And requirement is to find all the matches as list of strings in multiline statement which are within $< and >$ excluding the delimiters(i.e. $< and >$).

Comment: Please take a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/AUOjWU). Let me know if there is anything missing.

Comment: This worked for me. But it includes delimiters also.           string text = "$< xxx.xxx() >$ normal $< yyy() >$ 234 ${ zzz = }$";
             string patter = @"\$<((?:(?!\$<|>\$)[\s\S])*)>\$";
          
            MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(text, patter, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

            foreach (Match match in m)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }

Comment: You are using **`match.Value`**. Don't. Use **`match.Groups[1].Value`**.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will do the work:

```
(?<=\$<).*(?=>\$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oY6mO2/1

Comment: string text = "$< xxx.xxx() >$ normal $< yyy() >$ 234 ${ zzz = }$";
             string patter = @"(?<=\$<).*(?=>\$)";
          
            Match m = Regex.Match(text, patter, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

            foreach (Group g in m.Groups)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(g.Value);
            }      Answer : xxx.xxx() >$ normal $< yyy() . Where I am expecting2 groups xxx.xxx() and yyy() only

Answer (score 0):

To find this pattern in php you have this REGEX code for find any patten,

/$<(.*?)>$/s

For Example:

```
        $arrayWhichStoreKeyValueArrayOfYourPattern= array();
        preg_match_all('/$<(.*?)>$/s', 
        $yourcontentinwhichyoufind,         
        $arrayWhichStoreKeyValueArrayOfYourPattern);
        for($i=0;$i<count($arrayWhichStoreKeyValueArrayOfYourPattern[0]);$i++)
        {
            $content=
                     str_replace(
                      $arrayWhichStoreKeyValueArrayOfYourPattern[0][$i], 
                      constant($arrayWhichStoreKeyValueArrayOfYourPattern[1][$i]), 
                      $yourcontentinwhichyoufind);
        }
```

using this example you will replace value using same name constant content in this var **$yourcontentinwhichyoufind**

For example you have string like this which has also same named constant.

```
**global.php**
//in this file my constant declared.

define("MYNAME","Hiren Raiyani");
define("CONSTANT_VAL","contant value");

**demo.php**
$content="Hello this is $<MYNAME>$ and this is simple demo to replace $<CONSTANT_VAL>$";
$myarr= array();
        preg_match_all('/$<(.*?)>$/s', $content,      $myarray);
        for($i=0;$i<count($myarray[0]);$i++)
        {
            $content=str_replace(
                      $myarray[0][$i], 
                      constant($myarray[1][$i]), 
                      $content);
        }
```

I think as i know that's all.

Comment: That will still combine multiple tags on the further results after the first one. In the string "$<yo>$ $<yo>$" the content [yo>$ $<yo] from the middle is a valid match and **will** be amongst the returned data. For optimization reasons, he had the right idea with [^>]* in between, there.